# Separating copied cells

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I'm trying to conduct a code which will split up a cell into 3 different parts. Im trying to split up the dates in column "p" and inserting the 3 different parts in the columns "R:T". However somehow the code only pastes the the date in column R, as you can see in the picture attached. Whats wrong with the code?

```
Range("Q4:Q65000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("R4"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Because you declared your destination as `Destination:=Range("R4")`

Comment: Can you attach picture of desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue you have is that your code sees the date as it's long value not the format that you see it in.
Why not just use Excel formulas to handle this though?

Column `R` would be `=DAY(Q4)`

Column `S` would be `=MONTH(Q4)`

Column `T` would be `=YEAR(Q4)`

Comment: Thats a good point, im sorry for the stupid question. It works now, thank you very much. Im new to VBA so im trying to use it for almost everything, might be stupid.

Comment: For completeness - you can also use this YEAR, MONTH and DAY in VBA - something like `YEAR(ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("Q4"))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would suffice

```
Dim lastRow As Long

Set lastRow = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lastRow

    Range("R" & i).Value = Mid(Range("Q" & i).Value, 1, 2)
    Range("S" & i).Value = Mid(Range("Q" & i).Value, 4, 2)
    Range("T" & i).Value = Mid(Range("Q" & i).Value, 7, 4)

Next i
```

Loop through all rows that are affected and split the date into its parts.

This is given that the date will always be in the format

```
dd-MM-yyyy
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just used the suggested option above.